# Datatable How to make first field clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatable with server side processing.

Here is my data

```
name   type   cost
abc    a      $5
bac    d      $10
```

I want first field clickable to `mydomain.com/?abc`
second field to `mydomain.com?bac`

but data is populating with mysql so don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to generate content for a cell.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
      {
         targets: 0,
         render: function(data, type, full, meta){
            if(type === 'display'){
               data = '<a href="' + encodeURI('http://www.example.com/?' + data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }

            return data;
         }
      }
   ]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/h3xk1kaL/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try building a calculated column and adding anchor to it. Below example from [this reference page](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) and [this thread on calculated columns](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25675/how-to-display-computed-column-dynamically-using-jquery-datatables) might give you an idea how to do it.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
    }
  } ]
} );
```

If you want to capture a click event and handle it in a custom way it's a little more complicated. When I needed to hack something like this together a while back I ended up having to use calculated columns to add HTML classes to cells I wanted to make interactive, wait for DataTable to be filled (listen to `on load complete` or `on init complete`, not sure now), query DOM for elements with HTML classes I used and attaching my event handlers in this manner. Main reason for this being when document initializes and attaches handlers to DOM elements, table rows are not there yet, so event's wouldn't get automagically attached.